# Configuring two different database - Postgres SQL and cassandra Db in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

In our application, the DB is configuration done using Spring boot starter JPA and application.properties -

```
spring.datasource.url= postgres
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Now, I want to add the cassandra db in the same application using proerties of spring data cassandra:

```
spring.data.cassandra.XX
```

Can someone please suggest way so that I can connect the different repository to connect to either of the database.

I don't want to make changes in the existing JPA repository part.

Is there a way to configure Cassandra separately and how to connect two different db from same application.

Comment: Did you checked [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases). Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

We need to follow the below steps.

1. Define two separate database configuration files, one for PostgreSQL and another for Cassandra in application.properties or the config file(for example in the case of tomcat context.xml).
2. Write two Java Datasource configuration file for both databases where we need to configure entityManager, entityManagerFactory, transactionManager etc.
3. Define two repositories one for PostgreSQL and the other for Cassandra

[Here](https://javatute.com/spring-boot/how-to-configure-multiple-datasource-in-spring-boot/) is working example where Mysql and Oracle database have been used.